# Wordpress Themeforest (icloudconnected.com) redirect?

Tags: wordpress, performance, wordpress-theming, pagespeed

Hi I am in the process of optimising my wordpress website. I have been doing speed tests on pingdom and I have been getting these themeforest.net redirects I'm not sure where the source is. please see attached results

https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/doM2dF/http://planspluspermits.com.au

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3].

Does anyone know how to get rid of them? I cant seem to find the answer... has it been hacked?

Comment: Checked the report and those Themeforest requests didn't show up for me. Also, I believe this is something you should be asking to Theme Forest's support team directly.

Comment: Maybe these requests only happen when logged into the Wordpress admin? I would imagine off the top of my head these would be requests to check if your Themeforest plugins need updates? Do you have the `Envato Market` plugin installed?